# Application caused by some Fatal exception

Tags: android, eclipse, nullpointerexception

I have developed my application on android 2.3.6 (API 10) which works fine then I take exit from the Activity but its service is executing on background after 1 hour when I run it again then It due to some Fatal Exception it force stop but run again and work fine.

Please help me to understand this stack trace and help me solve this.
 Thanks in advance.

**OnOffScreen Class:**

```
public class OnOffScreen extends Activity {

private TextView txtDevId,txtdevTag,txtOnOffSt,btnonoffMain,lblAlarm,txtMonitor,txtVersion,txtOcc;
private TextView txtOnOffDevType,txtTimerApp,txtStartTime,txtStartAct,txtStopTime,txtStopAct;
private ListView lstDeviceInfo;
private Button btnReport,btnOn,btnOff,btnConfig,btnStatus;
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private Context context;
private ExceptionDialog dlg;
private SharedPreferences prefs;
private DataBaseAdapter dba;
private UtilityFunction utility;
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private ImageView imgMain; 
private String DevId,SwId;
private Bundle bundle;
private SendSMS smsSend;
private SMSReceiver receivedSms;
private Cursor cursor,curCord;
private customCursorAdapter adpt;
private TableRow trSwitchId;
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private ConstantClass ccl;
private static String SMS_RECEIVED = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
public OnOffScreen(){

    dba = new DataBaseAdapter(this);        
    smsSend = new SendSMS(this);
    receivedSms = new SMSReceiver(this);
    utility = new UtilityFunction(this);
     ccl = new ConstantClass();
}

  @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        final boolean isCsTitle = requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.onoffscr);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        if(isCsTitle)
            getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.title);
        final TextView mtxTitle = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lblMyTitle);
        mtxTitle.setText("Device On/Off Screen");
        ConstantClass.Clear_Main_Screen=false;
        ConstantClass.afterSendGotoMain = true;
        try{
            if(dba.IsConOpenOrClose()==false)
                dba.Open();
        bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(bundle!=null){           
            DevId = bundle.getString("devIdTag");
            SwId = bundle.getString("SwIdTag");
            prefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.putString("DeviceId", DevId);
            editor.putString("SwitchId", SwId);
            //////finally saved the data/////////
            editor.commit();
        }
        txtDevId = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtOnScDevID);
        txtdevTag = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtOnScDevTag);
        txtOnOffSt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtOnScDevStatus);
        txtMonitor = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtOnScDevMonitor);
        txtOnOffDevType = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtonoffDevType);
        txtVersion = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtOnOffDevAppVer);
        lstDeviceInfo = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lstDeviceInfo);
        lblAlarm = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lblOnOffAlarm);
        txtTimerApp = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtOnOffDevTimer);
        txtOcc = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtOnOffDevOcc);
        txtStartTime = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtOnOffStartTime);
        txtStartAct = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtOnOffDevStartAct);
        txtStopTime = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtOnOffDevStopTime);
        txtStopAct = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtOnOffDevStopAct);
        //imgMain = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgOnOffDevice);
        btnOn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnOnOffOn);
        btnOff = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnOnOffOff);
        btnStatus = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStatus);
        btnConfig = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnOnOffConfig);
        btnReport = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnOnOffSeeReport);
        btnonoffMain = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnOnOffMain);
        trSwitchId = (TableRow)findViewById(R.id.tbRowSwitchId);
        btnOn.setOnClickListener(btnClick);         
        btnOn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.onbutton);
        btnOff.setOnClickListener(btnClick);
        btnOff.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.offbutton);
        btnStatus.setOnClickListener(btnClick);
        btnStatus.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.checkstatus);
        btnConfig.setOnClickListener(btnClick);
        btnonoffMain.setOnClickListener(btnClick);
        btnReport.setOnClickListener(btnClick);         
        if(SwId.equals("0000")){
            trSwitchId.setVisibility(TableRow.GONE);
        }else
            trSwitchId.setVisibility(TableRow.VISIBLE);

        /************Filling the Coordinator number to cursor***************/           
          curCord = dba.getCoord(dba.CurrentWorkingCoordinator(DataBaseAdapter.Key_SendCoord, 1));
            if(curCord!=null){
            ConstantClass.address = curCord.getString(curCord.getColumnIndex(DataBaseAdapter.Key_MbNo)).toString();
            startManagingCursor(curCord);           
            }

                cursor = dba.SelFromDeviceStorage(DevId, SwId);         
                startManagingCursor(cursor);        
            if (cursor.getCount()>0){
                fillControl(cursor);            
            }
            String tag = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DataBaseAdapter.Key_DevTag));
            String alarm =utility.ReturnAlarm(DevId, tag);
            lblAlarm.setText(alarm);
            lblAlarm.setFocusable(true);
        lblAlarm.setOnClickListener(btnClick);
        }catch(SQLiteException e){
            Toast.makeText(this,e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }finally{
            if(curCord!=null)
                curCord.close();
        }
  }
  View.OnClickListener btnClick = new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.lblOnOffAlarm:
            if(lblAlarm.getText().toString()!=null){
                dlg = new ExceptionDialog(OnOffScreen.this,"Alarm " ,lblAlarm.getText().toString());
                dlg.show();
            }
            break;
        case R.id.btnOnOffOn:
            try{
            //ConstantClass.address = "5556";
                if (ConstantClass.timer != null)
                    ConstantClass.timer.cancel();
                ConstantClass.timer = new Timer();
                ConstantClass.timer.schedule(new AuditTimerTask(OnOffScreen.this), 300000);
            String msg = "<"+Integer.toHexString(26)+"3" + txtDevId.getText().toString() + SwId + Integer.toHexString(1)+">";
            smsSend.send_SMS( msg.toUpperCase());
            ////////go to mainn Screen //////

            }catch(Exception e){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            break;
        case R.id.btnOnOffOff:
            try{
                //ConstantClass.address = "5556";
                if (ConstantClass.timer != null)
                    ConstantClass.timer.cancel();
                ConstantClass.timer = new Timer();
                ConstantClass.timer.schedule(new AuditTimerTask(OnOffScreen.this),300000);
                String msg = "<"+Integer.toHexString(26)+"3" + txtDevId.getText().toString() + SwId + Integer.toHexString(0)+">";
                smsSend.send_SMS( msg.toUpperCase());
                //////////now going to Main Screen//////////////                    
                }catch(Exception e){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            break;
        case R.id.btnStatus:
            try{
                if (ConstantClass.timer != null)
                    ConstantClass.timer.cancel();
                ConstantClass.timer = new Timer();
                ConstantClass.timer.schedule(new AuditTimerTask(OnOffScreen.this),300000);
                String msg = "<"+Integer.toHexString(26)+"3" + txtDevId.getText().toString() + SwId + Integer.toHexString(9)+">";
                smsSend.send_SMS( msg.toUpperCase());
            }catch(Exception e){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            break;
        case R.id.btnOnOffConfig:
            /*
             * code for go on to the Config Device Screen from OnOffScreen *
             */
            Intent onOffConfig = new Intent(OnOffScreen.this,ConfigDevice.class);
            onOffConfig.putExtra("DeviceId", txtDevId.getText().toString());
            onOffConfig.putExtra("SwId", SwId);
            OnOffScreen.this.startActivity(onOffConfig);
            break;
        case R.id.btnOnOffMain:
            /*
             * code for go on to main Zigbee Activity Class from the OnOffScreen *
             */
            try{
            Intent onOffMain = new Intent(OnOffScreen.this,ZigbeeActivity.class);
            onOffMain.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

            if(dba.IsConOpenOrClose()==false)
                dba.Open();
            String sQuery = new String("UPDATE " + ConstantClass.dbName[3] + " SET " + DataBaseAdapter.Key_AlarmID + " = " + "0" +
            " WHERE " + DataBaseAdapter.Key_AlarmDevID + " = ?");
            dba.UpdateQuery(sQuery, DevId); 
            OnOffScreen.this.startActivity(onOffMain);
            }catch(Exception e){
                Toast.makeText(OnOffScreen.this, "On OffScreen " +  e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            break;
        case R.id.btnOnOffSeeReport:
            Intent rptInt = new Intent(OnOffScreen.this,ReportHistory.class);
            String dTag = null,stag = null,devsr=null, pic=null;

            if(cursor!=null){
                DevId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DataBaseAdapter.Key_DevID));
                SwId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DataBaseAdapter.Key_SwID));
                dTag = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DataBaseAdapter.Key_DevTag));
                stag = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DataBaseAdapter.Key_SwTag));
                devsr = String.valueOf(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DataBaseAdapter.Key_DevSr)));
                pic = String.valueOf(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DataBaseAdapter.Key_DevPic)));

                    rptInt.putExtra("DeviceID",DevId);

                    rptInt.putExtra("SwitchId", SwId);

                    rptInt.putExtra("DeviceTag", dTag);

                    rptInt.putExtra("SwitchTag",stag );

                    rptInt.putExtra("DeviceSr", devsr);

                    rptInt.putExtra("DevicePic", pic);
            OnOffScreen.this.startActivity(rptInt);
            }
            else
                OnOffScreen.this.startActivity(rptInt);
            break;
        }
    }
};
@Override
public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();        
        ///////registering the Receiver for sms receiving///////////
            registerReceiver(smsSend.sms_send,smsSend.getSentIntentFilter());
             registerReceiver(smsSend.sms_delivered,smsSend.getDeliveredFilter());
            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(SMS_RECEIVED);
            registerReceiver(receivedSms,filter);    

}
  @Override 
  public void onResume(){
      super.onResume(); 
     try{                    
              dba.Open();            
      //////loading the prefrences////////
      SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
      DevId = prefs.getString("DeviceId", "");
      SwId = prefs.getString("SwitchId", "");         
      cursor = dba.SelFromDeviceStorage(DevId, SwId);           
        startManagingCursor(cursor);        
        if (cursor.getCount()>0){
            fillControl(cursor);            
        }
      }catch(Exception e){
          Log.d("Resume On Off", e.getMessage());

      }
  }

  @Override
  public void onPause(){
      super.onPause();  
      if(cursor!=null)
          cursor.close();         
    ConstantClass.Clear_Main_Screen = true;


 }   
  @Override
  public void onBackPressed(){
      try{
            Intent onOffMain = new Intent(OnOffScreen.this,ZigbeeActivity.class);
            onOffMain.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

            if(dba.IsConOpenOrClose()==false)
                dba.Open();
            String sQuery = new String("UPDATE " + ConstantClass.dbName[3] + " SET " + DataBaseAdapter.Key_AlarmID + " = " + "0" +
            " WHERE " + DataBaseAdapter.Key_AlarmDevID + " = ?");
            dba.UpdateQuery(sQuery, DevId); 
            OnOffScreen.this.startActivity(onOffMain);
            }catch(Exception e){
                Toast.makeText(OnOffScreen.this, "On OffScreen " +  e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
  }
  @Override
  public void onDestroy(){        
      super.onDestroy();
      unregisterReceiver(receivedSms);
      unregisterReceiver(smsSend.sms_send);
      unregisterReceiver(smsSend.sms_delivered);
      if(cursor!=null)
          cursor.close();   
     if(dba!=null)
          dba.Close();
  }
  public String setDtTime(String temp){
        String dd,mm,yy,hh,min;
        dd = temp.substring(0, 2);
        mm = temp.substring(2, 4);
        int mon = Integer.valueOf(mm);
        mm = Integer.toString(mon+1);
        if(mm.length()!=2)
            mm = "0" + mm;
        yy  =   temp.substring(4, 6);
        hh = temp.substring(6, 8);
        min = temp.substring(8, 10);
    return dd+"/" + mm + "/" + yy + " " + hh + ":" + min; 
    }
  public void fillControl(Cursor cursor){
      try{
      if(cursor!=null)
          cursor.moveToFirst();
     adpt = new customCursorAdapter(this,cursor);
     lstDeviceInfo.setAdapter(adpt);
     txtDevId.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DataBaseAdapter.Key_DevID)).toString());
     txtDevId.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
     txtdevTag.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DataBaseAdapter.Key_DevTag)));
     txtdevTag.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

     if(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DataBaseAdapter.Key_SwID)).toString().equals("0000")){
         txtOnOffDevType.setText("Plug");
     }else
         txtOnOffDevType.setText("Switch");
     txtOnOffDevType.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
     if(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DataBaseAdapter.Key_DevOnOff))==1)
         txtOnOffSt.setText("ON");
     else
         txtOnOffSt.setText("OFF");
     txtMonitor.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
     if(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DataBaseAdapter.Key_DevRu))==1)
         txtMonitor.setText("Yes");
     else
         txtMonitor.setText("NO");

     txtOnOffSt.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

     if(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DataBaseAdapter.Key_DevTmr))==2)
         txtTimerApp.setText("Yes");
     else
         txtTimerApp.setText("NO");
     txtTimerApp.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
     if((cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DataBaseAdapter.Key_DevOc))==1)|| cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DataBaseAdapter.Key_DevOc))==0){
         txtOcc.setText("Once");
     }else if(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DataBaseAdapter.Key_DevOc))==2){
         txtOcc.setText("Daily");
     }else if(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DataBaseAdapter.Key_DevOc))==4){
         txtOcc.setText("Annualy");
     }else 
         txtOcc.setText("Weakly");

     txtOcc.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
     String onTime = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DataBaseAdapter.Key_DevOnTm)).toString();
        /* for catching the On Status Device */
        txtStartTime.setText(setDtTime( onTime));
        txtStartTime.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        if(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DataBaseAdapter.Key_DevOnSt))==1)
            txtStartAct.setText("ON");
        else
            txtStartAct.setText("OFF");
        txtStartAct.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        String offTime =cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DataBaseAdapter.Key_DevOffTm)).toString();
        /* for getting the timer Off act from the dbase*/


        txtStopTime.setText(setDtTime(offTime));
        txtStopTime.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        if(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DataBaseAdapter.Key_DevOffSt))==1)
            txtStopAct.setText("ON");
        else
            txtStopAct.setText("OFF");  
        txtStopAct.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        String tem = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DataBaseAdapter.Key_DevVersion));
        txtVersion.setText(tem.substring(0, 1)+ "." + tem.substring(1, 2) + "." + tem.substring(2));
        txtVersion.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
      }catch(Exception e){
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();          
      }
  }
}
```

---

**stack trace:**

```
06-15 14:37:35.734: E/AndroidRuntime(31310): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

06-15 14:37:35.734: E/AndroidRuntime(31310): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.zigbee/com.zigbee.OnOffScreen}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-15 14:37:35.734: E/AndroidRuntime(31310):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
06-15 14:37:35.734: E/AndroidRuntime(31310):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
06-15 14:37:35.734: E/AndroidRuntime(31310):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
06-15 14:37:35.734: E/AndroidRuntime(31310):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
06-15 14:37:35.734: E/AndroidRuntime(31310):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-15 14:37:35.734: E/AndroidRuntime(31310):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
06-15 14:37:35.734: E/AndroidRuntime(31310):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
06-15 14:37:35.734: E/AndroidRuntime(31310):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-15 14:37:35.734: E/AndroidRuntime(31310):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-15 14:37:35.734: E/AndroidRuntime(31310):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
06-15 14:37:35.734: E/AndroidRuntime(31310):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
06-15 14:37:35.734: E/AndroidRuntime(31310):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-15 14:37:35.734: E/AndroidRuntime(31310): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-15 14:37:35.734: E/AndroidRuntime(31310):    at com.zigbee.OnOffScreen.onCreate(OnOffScreen.java:122)
06-15 14:37:35.734: E/AndroidRuntime(31310):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
06-15 14:37:35.734: E/AndroidRuntime(31310):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
06-15 14:37:35.734: E/AndroidRuntime(31310):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: You have a `NullPointerException` in line 122 of OnOffScreen.java. Check or report the statement in that line.

Answer (score 1):

You have problem in this statement

```
if (SwId.equals("0000")) {
```

You are calling this statement in onCreate and you are initlizing it in onResume.

`SwId = prefs.getString("SwitchId", "");`

Thats the reason your getting Exception.Always remember when you start application it calls `onCreate` first before calling `onResume`.

You are initilizing it in onCreate only in folloing condition

```
if (bundle != null) {
    DevId = bundle.getString("devIdTag");
    SwId = bundle.getString("SwIdTag");
}
```

So at very first when your application will start bundle will be null and this condition will not get executed and your application will crash.

Comment: You are calling this only if bundle is not null.see my updated answer

Comment: Thanks for effort but this is not the issue because SwId is default 0000 Actually I have found that this is on onBackPressed event. ok

Answer (score 0):

You have NullPointerException because of null object try to debug your application